# ng repeat dosn't update itself after inserting new item using dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am just a beginner with angularJs , and i am trying to do CRUD Operations using $http and asp.net MVC :-

1. I am using ng-repeat to display list of "Terms" .
2. I have a
   button to display a dialog ,which in turn will be used to inserting
   new "Term".
3. ng-repeat works well and the dialog also displayed
   and i can insert new item successfully.

the problem is :-
- after inserting new term and closing the dialog , ng-repeat doesn't updating . and this the code i am using :

```
var glossayApp = angular.module("glossaryApp", ['ui.bootstrap.dialog']);

var ctrl = glossayApp.controller("termController", function ($scope, $http, $route, $dialog, $window) {
$scope.terms = [];

$scope.init = function () {
    $http.get("/Home/List").success(function (data) {
        $scope.terms = data;
    });
}
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.opts = { backdrop: true, keyboard: true, backdropClick: true, templateUrl: '/Home/Add', controller: 'dialogController' };
    var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
    d.open().then(function (term) {
        if (term) {
            $http.post('/Home/Add/', { Name: term.name, Definition: term.definition }).success(function () {
                $scope.init();
            });
        }
    });
}
});
glossayApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'termController', templateUrl: '/Home/list'
}).when('/Details:id', {
    controller: 'termController', templateUrl: '/Home/details'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
});


var dialogController = glossayApp.controller('dialogController', function ($scope, dialog) {
$scope.save = function (term) {
    dialog.close(term);
}
$scope.close = function () {
    dialog.close();
}
});
```

and this the HTML I am using in ngrepeat :-

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-init="init();">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Term
        </td>
        <td>
            Definition
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="term in terms">
    <td>
        {{term.Name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{term.Definition}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" name="Add" value="Add New Term" ng-click="add();" />
```

Comment: Is it successfully posting the data and returning it when you perform the get?

Comment: @Mike Robinson, yes it is!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the first glance , I guessed that the problem is the Scope , so I worked around it , I attached a CSS class to the table element which contains ng-repeat directive , this is my working code :

```
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.opts = { backdrop: true, keyboard: true, backdropClick: true, templateUrl: '/Home/Add', controller: 'dialogController' };
    var d = $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
    d.open().then(function (term) {
        if (term) {
            $http.post('/Home/Add/', { Name: term.name, Definition: term.definition }).success(function () {
                $http.get("/Home/GetData").success(function (data) {
                    var termscope = angular.element($(".term")).scope();
                    termscope.terms = data;
                    termscope.$apply();
                });

            });
        }
    });
}
```

I get the scope of the table which contains ng-repeat using :-

```
 var termscope = angular.element($(".term")).scope();
```

and set terms variable again :-

```
termscope.terms = data;
```

and at the end i need to call $apply to update view(html).

```
termscope.$apply();
```

and it works well and updated the ng-repeat (view) after closing the dialog with no problem .

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solving using Modal instead of dialog , and it works well.

dialog :- http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog

Modal  :- http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: may be is a dialog issue, I post this problem in :
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/529

Comment: The links dosen't render.